# json_decode returning an array of 1

Tags: php, json, jsonp

I am trying to decode some JSON into a php array. Here's the code excerpt:

```
$getfile="{"fname":"bob","lname":"thomas","cascade":"bthomas","loc":"res","place":"home 2"}";
$arr = json_decode($getfile, true);
$arr['day3'] = $selecter;
echo(print_r($arr));
```

The only thing that gets returned is '1'. I've checked JSONLint and it is valid json, so I'm wondering why json_decode is failing. I also tried checking what the array is before adding the day3 key to it, and I still return a '1'. Any help is appreciated!

Actual code:

```
$getfile = "";
    $getfile = file_get_contents($file);
    if ($getfile == "") {
        writeLog("Error reading file.");
    }
    writeLog("getfile is " . $getfile);
    writeLog("Decoding JSON data");
    $arr = json_decode($getfile, true);
    writeLog("Decoded raw: " . print_r($arr));
    writeLog("Editing raw data. Adding data for day " . $day);
    $arr['day3'] = $selecter;
    writeLog(print_r($arr));
    $newfile = json_enconde($arr);
    writeLog($newfile);
    if (file_put_contents($file, $newfile)) {
        writeLog("Wrote file to " . $file);
        echo $newfile;
    } else {
        writeLog("Error writting file");
    }
```

These are the contents of $file (it's a text file)

```
{"fname":"Bob","lname":"Thomas","cascade":"bthomas","loc":"res","place":"home 2"}
```

Comment: Can you post your actual code? I'd expect a parsing error rather than a `1`.

Comment: Try putting single quotes on the ends of your JSON string.

Comment: @mario He is seeing `1` because of the nested `echo(print_r())`, the `print_r()` call returns `bool (true)` which when `echo`ed results in `1`. You'd still expect to see the array output as well though... **EDIT** Oh actually it would work that way if `json_decode()` returned `NULL` (possibly `FALSE` as well, not sure, I'd have to check)

Comment: Doesn't $getfile = ""; make the JSON a string when the file gets contents?

Comment: @Vikram The `$getfile = "";` is redundant and can be removed, the current type of the variable does not affect the new type when it is reassigned.

Comment: Okay, changed that. Would that effect the array printing as 1?

Comment: @Vikram need to remove the `echo` from around the `print_r()` call to stop the `1` appearing. `print_r()` outputs data directly, it doesn't need to be wrapped in `echo`. I would replace that whole line with `var_dump($arr);` to see what's actually going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>We still don't know what's in your file. However if:</s>

```
"{"fname":"bob","lname":"thomas","cascade":"bthomas","loc":"res","place":"home 2"}"
```

Then the extraneous outer double quotes will screw the JSON, and [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) will return NULL. Use [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/json_last_error) to find out. Might also be a UTF-8 BOM or something else ...

Anyway, the `1` is the result from [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r). print_r outputs directly, you don't need the echo. Also for debugging rather use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump)

---

More specifically you would want the `print_r` output returned (instead of the boolean success result `1`) and then write that to the log.

So use:

```
      writeLog(print_r($arr, TRUE));
```

Notice the `TRUE` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

First, use a single quote. That will cause a parse error

```
$getfile= '{"fname":"bob","lname":"thomas","cascade":"bthomas","loc":"res","place":"home 2"}';
```

I assume you have already declared $selecter and it has been assigned to some value.

Remove echo from `echo(print_r($arr))` You don't need echo. print_r will also output. If you use echo, it will display 1 at the end of array.

The working code:

```
$getfile = '{"fname":"bob","lname":"thomas","cascade":"bthomas","loc":"res","place":"home 2"}';
    $arr = json_decode($getfile, true);
    $selecter = 'foobar';
    $arr['day3'] = $selecter;
    print_r($arr);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when doing it like this:

```
if ($arr = json_decode($getfile, true)) {
    $arr['day3'] = $selecter;
    echo(print_r($arr));
}
```

Decoding it outside of if was the solution.